# What is the best, efficient approach to do a quick forms based web project?

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, cakephp, symfony1

I am a database guy and its been few years since I did anything with PHP (no MVC experience). I now have to work on a Data Entry project - a form that a user will fill and submit data to the database. I figured this is much more efficient than a spreadsheet approach.

All I need is :

1) Authentication
2) Validation of data
3) Submit data to the database.

How would you suggest I proceed? I have 2 weeks time for this project. Should I dabble with MVC and do it the industry standard way or go with good 'ol procedural PHP way?

Some things I looked at :
1) Symfony
2) CakePHP
3) Django

Any ideas, suggestions are really appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use django to two years, and I had an experience of a project using cakephp and hated it. Django was able to show better in all aspects, much of it takes the python and transparent way how the framework works. I strongly recommend Django.

Comment: I second the recommendation to use Django if you can. After defining your models and setting up your database, there are generic views that can do a lot of what you need out of the box.

Comment: +1 Django.  Build the models, tweak the forms, use the admin interface.  Write no actual "code".

Comment: If this is true, then thats exactly what I want! I work with Python every day but haven't touched Django. I am hoping the installation of Django on Ubuntu + Apache2 will be straight forward!

Answer (score 2):

You should use Symfony with Doctrine : all you'll have to do is define your schema, and you will be able to **generate** your forms. Doctrine has [its own validation system](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_0/hu/data-validation), many constraints can be specified in the schema itself.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into Symfony w/ Doctrine and decide which way to go. I work with Python, so Django isn't a bad idea. Whichever proves easy to install and grasp, that should do it! Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just doing some one off data gathering, you could save yourself the work and use Google Spreadsheets ( Create New -> Form).  I know you mentioned spreadsheets, but once you've got the data you can export it and do what you want with it.

It's a simple solution and might not fit, but if it does it'll cut your time down to a couple of hours instead of a couple of weeks.

Comment: Google docs is ruled out since it is dynamic forms I have to work on. Some entries may have multiple sets of data and some won't. I think a framework approach will be efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly think you can learn enough about cakephp to be lethal in less than a half a day if you follow Andrew Perkins' tutorials

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nO9oSQhRa9s